# how to hide an <li>tag after checking the condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

In my application, a user can login and go to their profile page. The application checks the condition; if the user is merchant, then it adds a business section, otherwise no need for that. If the `user_type` value is 1, then he is a merchant.

My code is this,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1primary" data-toggle="tab">Dashboard</a></li>
    <?php  
  if (($this->session->userdata('user_type'))==1)
  { ?>                                                        

          <li><a href="#tab2primary" data-toggle="tab">Business</a></li>

    <?  }  
   ?>  

    <li><a href="#tab3primary" data-toggle="tab">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4primary" data-toggle="tab">Event Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5primary" data-toggle="tab">Business Reviews</a></li>
</ul>
```

But in the two cases, neither gets the business tab.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can hardly understand, do your code work or not? What is your goal?

Comment: the business tab not visible.My goal is if the business tab exists only when the user_type=1

Comment: Try changing your IF statement, to this; `if ($this->session->userdata('user_type) == 1)`

Comment: no change...any mistake in this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to set your sessions userdata?

Comment: Instead of leaving people to make guesses at your question, then get down-voted because their work isn't what you want, take the time to [edit] your question to make it clear. Include pictures if it helps.

Comment: After you set your session `$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);` can you print the session data, and see what's set?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are initializing the session, and setting the value, but just in case, **on the controller** (or you can add it to autoload).

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

And where the user logs in, you should add the value to be retrieved later:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_type', 1); //Change the number based on your current settings for different users.
```

To double check the value stored on the session, you can just output the value like this:

```
var_dump($this->session->userdata('user_type'));
```

or

```
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
```

Last, but not least, remember that to be able to create a session, you need to setup an encryptation_key on application/config/config.php, open the file and set:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";
```

And if you're wondering what to use as a key, just add a simple pass phrase, it will be encoded automatically.

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the session library no longer requires an encryption_key in the latest CI.

Comment: Based on the documentation for 2.2.0, it's still required https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html
It might not be mandatory, I always added automatically to my projects. I'll double check that this afternoon and update my comment.